# GraphQL: Use input type and one of its fields in the same query

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm wondering how to use both an input type and one of its fields as arguments in the same GraphQL query. I think there are a few valid solutions, but I'm wondering which (if any) are best practice.

Consider the following hypothetical query. We get players by location and status, and team members who are in the same location, but the `member` field only has a `location` argument:

```
input PlayerInput {
  location: String!
  status: Int!
}

query getPlayers($playerInput: PlayerInput) {
  players(playerInput: $playerInput) {
    name
    team {
      name
      members(location: ???) { // <-- How to access playerInput.location?
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can think of a few ways to solve this:

**1. Change the query to take individual arguments**

```js
query getPlayers($location: String!, $status: Int!) {
  players(playerInput: { location: $location, status: $status }) {
    name
    team {
      name
      members(location: $location) {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Update the schema so `members` takes the right input type**

```js
query getPlayers($playerInput: PlayerInput) {
  players(playerInput: $playerInput) {
    name
    team {
      name
      members(playerInput: $playerInput) { // <-- Requires changing schema
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem great for a few reasons, and would only work if you have the ability to update the schema.

**3. Pass `location` in as a redundant individual argument**

```js
query getPlayers($playerInput: PlayerInput, $location: String!) {
  players(playerInput: $playerInput) {
    name
    team {
      name
      members(location: $location) {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This seems fine, just that there's some duplication when creating the query:

```js
const location = 'US';
const status = 1;

fetch({
  query: getPlayersQuery,
  variables: {
    location,
    playerInput: {
      location,
      status,
    }
  }
})...
```

Are any of these the preferred way of doing something like this? Are there other ways I haven't considered?

Comment: I would definitely prefer #1 or #3 over #2 - changing the schema only to support one special query is a no-go. Unless you *really* plan to make the `members` of a team filterable by `isActive`, and your query really wants to get only active teammates of active players and inactive mates of inactive players.

Comment: That makes sense - #2 seemed like a no-go to me too, just wanted to confirm. #1 seems the cleanest to me, just looking for a second opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilizing multiple arguments over a single argument that takes an input type (option #1) sometimes makes sense *conceptually*, but it lacks any other real merit and has the downside of making your variable definitions unnecessarily verbose. In my opinion, using input types typically enforces typings better as well. Changing your schema just to avoid duplication is not worth it.

Utilizing the same input object type on both fields (option #2) should only be done if both fields actually need all those input fields. Doing it just to avoid duplication is a bad idea -- it effectively introduces inputs that are unused, which is not a good experience for any *other* developer consuming the API.

Option #3 is fine. It also puts the ball in the front end dev's court -- if they *wanted* to avoid the duplication, they could also just as easily do this without you introducing additional arguments:

```
query getPlayers($status: Int!, $location: String!) {
  players(playerInput: { status: $status, location: $location }) {
    name
    team {
      name
      members(location: $location) {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**However, the duplication is most likely actually a good thing.** You don't encounter these scenarios too much in the wild because we're dealing with *graphs* of data. The `players`, `team` and `members` fields are all part of a hierarchy, where the parent field constrains the data returned by the child -- for example, `members` doesn't return all members, just members of that particular team. That means, in *most cases* if you constrain `players` to only include data from a particular location, you're also constraining the data returned by child fields like `members`. If you feel like `members` needs its own `location` argument, **then that implies that the two location inputs *could* be different**. If they could be different, they should be represented as two separate variables to maximize flexibility and query reuse.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you! Giving flexibility to the frontend dev is what I like about options 1 and 3 too. One thing - isn't your example the same as option 1? Thanks for your explanation in terms of hierarchy/constraints, that's helpful!

Comment: No, look at two examples again. In my snippet, `players` still takes a single argument named `playerInput` -- the difference is instead of providing a single variable, we're constructing the object and providing multiple variables for its fields. I'm not saying this is necessarily better, but if you're determined to only provide the location once this is one way to do it *without changing the field to accept multiple arguments as in your first snippet*.

Comment: I've looked at them again, they are the same - in example 1, the _query_ takes multiple arguments, but `players` takes a single `playerInput` argument, constructed out of the arguments passed into the query. (I edited the example because previously it was using an `isActive` argument, but didn't make any other changes). Again, thank you for your explanation!